# data manipulation inside nested array

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the below data structure,

```
data = {
  data: [{
    areas: [{
      sections: [{
          rjf: [{
            type: 'heading-1'
            text: 'Sample Heading',
          }]
        },
        {
          rjf: [{
              type: 'paragraph',
              depth: 0,
              text: 'This website is offered to you by:',
              inlineStyleRanges: [],
              inlineEntityRanges: []
            },
            {
              "type": "ordered-list-item",
              "text": "Ordered Item A",
            },
            {
              "type": "unordered-list-item",
              "text": "Ordered Item B",
            },
            {
              type: 'paragraph',
              depth: 0,
              text: 'This website is offered to you by:',
              inlineStyleRanges: [],
              inlineEntityRanges: []
            },
            {
              "type": "ordered-list-item",
              "text": "Ordered Item A",
            },
            {
              "type": "unordered-list-item",
              "text": "Ordered Item B",
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  }]
};
```

I'm trying to group all the type which as `ordered-list-item` & `unordered-list-item` into new object. Something like below,

```
{
    "type": 'list',
    "items": [
      {
        "type": "ordered-list-item",
        "text": "Ordered Item A",
      },
      {
        "type": "unordered-list-item",
        "text": "Ordered Item B",
      }
    ]
  }
```

After so much treble, I came with the below solution. This works fine.
But having an issue, In `rjf` if `ordered-list-item` & `unordered-list-item` not found nothing should be happen unfortunately and empty `list` getting added to `rjf`.

Below is the code snippet, please help me to fix this issue.

```js
const data = {
  data: [{
    areas: [{
      sections: [{
          rjf: [{
            text: 'Sample Heading',
          }]
        },
        {
          rjf: [{
              type: 'paragraph',
              depth: 0,
              text: 'This website is offered to you by:',
              inlineStyleRanges: [],
              inlineEntityRanges: []
            },
            {
              "type": "ordered-list-item",
              "text": "Ordered Item A",
            },
            {
              "type": "unordered-list-item",
              "text": "Ordered Item B",
            },
            {
              type: 'paragraph',
              depth: 0,
              text: 'This website is offered to you by:',
              inlineStyleRanges: [],
              inlineEntityRanges: []
            },
            {
              "type": "ordered-list-item",
              "text": "Ordered Item A",
            },
            {
              "type": "unordered-list-item",
              "text": "Ordered Item B",
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  }]
};
const moveToNewObject = (data) => {
  const sections = data[0].areas[0].sections;
  sections.forEach(data => {
    let list = data.rjf;
    let a = list.map((entry, index) => {
      return { ...entry,
        index,
        use: entry.type !== 'unordered-list-item' && entry.type !== 'ordered-list-item'
      }
    }).filter(entry => entry.use).map((entry, index, entries) => {
      const end = index < entries.length - 1 ? entries[index + 1].index : list.length - entry.index;
      return [{
        type: entry.type,
        text: entry.text
      }, {
        type: 'list',
        items: list.slice(entry.index + 1, entry.index + end)
      }]
    });
    console.log(a);
  });
}
console.log(moveToNewObject(data.data));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` has a very weird structure which makes it harder to be honest. The snippet below uses a function that uses `map` on all your sections, and if `rjf` type is `'unordered-list-item'` or `'ordered-list-item'`, it moves it to a new `rjf` of type `list` as `items`. Hopefully it's what you wanted.

And here's a fiddle if you want clearer code formatting:
https://jsfiddle.net/qce2vLr3/

```js
const data = {
  data: [
    {
      areas: [
        {
          sections: [
            {
              rjf: [
                {
                  text: 'Sample Heading',
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              rjf: [
                {
                  type: 'paragraph',
                  depth: 0,
                  text: 'This website is offered to you by:',
                  inlineStyleRanges: [],
                  inlineEntityRanges: []
                },
                {
                  "type": "ordered-list-item",
                  "text": "Ordered Item A",
                },
                {
                  "type": "unordered-list-item",
                  "text": "Ordered Item B",
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const moveToNewObject = (data) => {
 const sections = data[0].areas[0].sections; // why is data an array?
  return sections.map((section) => {
   if (section.rjf) {
     const looseItems = section.rjf.filter((rjf) => rjf.type && ['ordered-list-item', 'unordered-list-item'].includes(rjf.type));
      if (looseItems.length) {
       return { 
         rjf: [
           ...section.rjf,
           { 
            type: 'list',
             items: looseItems 
           }
          ].filter((rjf) => rjf.type && !['ordered-list-item', 'unordered-list-item'].includes(rjf.type))
        }
      }
      return section;
    }
    return section;
  })
}

data.data[0].areas[0].sections = moveToNewObject(data.data);
console.log(data.data);
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a solution that "groups" your lists by multiple headings: https://jsfiddle.net/pkLyd0gh/

```js
const data = {
  data: [
    {
      areas: [
        {
          sections: [
            {
              rjf: [
                {
                  text: 'Sample Heading',
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              rjf: [
                {
                  "type": "heading-1",
                  "text": "A title",
                },
                {
                  "type": "ordered-list-item",
                  "text": "Ordered Item A",
                },
                {
                  "type": "unordered-list-item",
                  "text": "Ordered Item B",
                },
                {
                  "type": "heading-2",
                  "text": "A title",
                },
                {
                  "type": "ordered-list-item",
                  "text": "Ordered Item C",
                },
                {
                  "type": "unordered-list-item",
                  "text": "Ordered Item D",
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const reformattedSections = (data) => {
 const sections = data[0].areas[0].sections;
  const listItemTypes = ['unordered-list-item', 'ordered-list-item'];
  return sections.map((section) => {
   let lastHeadingIndex = -1;
   return section.rjf.reduce((acc, current, index) => {
     if (!current.type || !listItemTypes.includes(current.type)) {
       lastHeadingIndex = acc.length;
        return [...acc, current]
      }
      else {
       let listObject = acc.find((el, i) => i > lastHeadingIndex && i < index && el.type === 'list');
        if (!listObject) {
         listObject = {
           type: 'list',
            items: [current]
          }
          return [...acc, listObject];
        }
        listObject.items = [...listObject.items, current];
       return acc;
      }
    }, [])
  })
}

data.data[0].areas[0].sections = reformattedSections(data.data);
console.log('sections', data.data);
```

Comment: Position of grouping `ordered-list-item` &  `unordered-list-item` is not maintained. For example, after the `list` if I get a `paragraph` grouping should stop.

Comment: Can't understand, it only groups `ordered-list-item` & `unordered-list-item` into type `list`. Your new example shows that the results are doubled?

Comment: Its not doubled, I can have multiple list items and I wanted to maintain its position. I've updated the question with  current & expected one

Comment: In current solutions which you provided, all list items are grouped at last. Expecting the output like this https://jsfiddle.net/2gjyrxkq/

Comment: If I understand correctly you want your array to be structured with `heading` type being followed by it's contents (i.e. type `list`)? It is probably doable (use `reduce` instead of `map` plus array destructuring) but I would advice you against doing that. Introducing such logic makes code hard to maintain and unreadable. Array is not a proper data structure for this kind of thing, you'd better use an objects such as `{ heading: <your heading object>, contents: <i.e. your list>` for this. If you get this input from your Backend, it's backend's job to provide it in readable format.

Comment: data structure cannot be changed due its backend complicity. I tried my level best to manipulate the data no luck so far.Yes you're understanding  is correct

Comment: I kind of came close, but getting an empty list added to `rjf` even if no list items are found. Is anytjing you help me wit ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a fiddle that does what you want.

Comment: Yes. Thanks so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

slice is a method on array's not on objects. DATA in your code is an Object

```
const a ={a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}
const b =[1,2,3,4]

//console.log(a.slice(1,3)) //this will return the error    
console.log(b.slice(1,3))
```

Hope it helps.